# Is it possible to check whether an IP address comes from a specific country without using GeoIP?

Tags: php, ip-address

So I want to check if the user is in specific county

```
    $ip = user ip;
$countryIP = some number;

    if($ip == $countryIP){echo 'okey';} else {echo 'not okey';}
```

I dont want to use database with geo location since I need it for only one country.Also i dont want to use third party services.

For example abc.go.com/watch is only for US and I want to do something similar to that

Thanks :)

Comment: The main issue is that while most IP addresses are already allocated to individual countries, some blocks are not; in addition, some allocations change, so you would need to update your code periodically.  Your best bet is to get a local database of IP address allocations and check against that.  If you tell us what country you're after, I may be able to help further

Comment: The country is Bulgaria. Now i check in countryipblocks.net and i copy some ip's then put them into array and check if my ip address exist. But that dosent work since my ip is 77.85.79.45 but in the block list is 77.85.0.0/16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, provided you're happy with checking Bulgaria against the block you indicated, then you can do it reasonably simply - all you need to do is convert the ip addresses to the numerical notation.

77.85.0.0/16 means any code from 77.85.0.0 to 77.85.255.255 - now convert these to a numerical values:

```
77*256^3+85*256^2+0*256+0 = 1297416192
77*256^3+85*256^2+255*256+255 = 1297481727
```

Now convert the IP you want to check in the same manner - and verify that it's between these two numbers.  Of course, it's not as simple as you are saying.  There are over 400 different blocks for Bulgaria.  If you care about it all, here's the full list of their numerical representation (as of the last update).  Check yourself, for example, here: http://www.countryipblocks.net/country-blocks/select-formats/

```
# Country: BULGARIA
# ISO Code: BG
# Total Networks: 497
# Total Subnets:  4,148,224
31.13.192.0/18
31.41.16.0/21
31.211.128.0/19
37.60.136.0/21
37.63.0.0/17
37.130.240.0/21
37.157.136.0/21
37.157.160.0/19
46.10.0.0/16
46.16.192.0/21
46.35.160.0/19
46.40.64.0/18
46.47.64.0/18
46.55.128.0/17
46.229.192.0/20
46.232.152.0/21
46.233.0.0/18
46.237.64.0/18
46.238.0.0/18
46.249.64.0/19
46.252.48.0/20
46.253.0.0/20
46.254.128.0/21
62.44.96.0/19
62.73.64.0/18
62.176.64.0/19
62.176.96.0/19
62.182.112.0/21
62.204.128.0/19
62.213.160.0/19
62.221.128.0/19
77.70.0.0/17
77.71.0.0/17
77.76.0.0/18
77.76.128.0/18
77.77.0.0/18
77.77.128.0/18
77.78.0.0/18
77.78.128.0/18
77.85.0.0/16
77.95.232.0/21
77.236.160.0/19
77.238.64.0/19
77.246.208.0/20
78.40.136.0/21
78.83.0.0/16
78.90.0.0/16
78.108.240.0/20
78.128.0.0/17
78.130.128.0/17
78.142.0.0/18
78.154.0.0/19
78.159.128.0/19
79.100.0.0/16
79.110.112.0/20
79.124.0.0/18
79.124.64.0/19
79.132.0.0/19
79.134.32.0/19
79.134.160.0/19
80.72.64.0/20
80.72.80.0/20
80.78.224.0/20
80.80.128.0/20
80.80.144.0/20
80.95.16.0/20
80.253.48.0/20
81.161.240.0/20
82.101.64.0/18
82.103.64.0/18
82.118.224.0/19
82.119.64.0/19
82.137.64.0/18
82.146.0.0/19
82.147.128.0/19
82.199.192.0/19
83.97.24.0/21
83.97.64.0/21
83.142.16.0/21
83.143.144.0/21
83.143.176.0/21
83.143.248.0/21
83.148.64.0/18
83.222.160.0/19
83.228.0.0/17
84.21.192.0/19
84.22.0.0/19
84.38.240.0/20
84.40.64.0/18
84.43.128.0/17
84.54.128.0/18
84.201.192.0/20
84.238.128.0/17
84.242.128.0/18
84.252.0.0/18
85.11.128.0/18
85.14.0.0/18
85.91.128.0/19
85.95.64.0/19
85.118.64.0/19
85.118.192.0/21
85.130.0.0/17
85.187.0.0/16
85.196.128.0/18
85.217.128.0/17
85.239.128.0/19
85.255.128.0/20
85.255.160.0/20
87.97.128.0/17
87.116.64.0/18
87.118.128.0/18
87.119.64.0/18
87.120.0.0/16
87.121.0.0/16
87.126.0.0/16
87.227.128.0/17
87.239.152.0/21
87.246.0.0/18
87.247.248.0/21
87.252.160.0/19
87.254.160.0/19
88.80.96.0/19
88.80.128.0/19
88.87.0.0/19
88.203.128.0/17
88.213.192.0/18
89.25.0.0/17
89.106.96.0/19
89.186.192.0/19
89.190.192.0/19
89.215.0.0/16
89.252.192.0/18
89.253.128.0/18
90.154.128.0/17
91.92.0.0/16
91.134.0.0/16
91.139.128.0/17
91.148.128.0/18
91.191.208.0/20
91.192.236.0/22
91.193.156.0/22
91.193.200.0/22
91.195.24.0/23
91.196.64.0/22
91.196.124.0/22
91.196.224.0/22
91.198.119.0/24
91.198.132.0/24
91.198.181.0/24
91.198.228.0/24
91.199.36.0/24
91.199.128.0/24
91.199.150.0/24
91.199.237.0/24
91.199.247.0/24
91.201.172.0/22
91.204.156.0/22
91.206.20.0/23
91.206.138.0/23
91.207.190.0/23
91.209.8.0/24
91.209.21.0/24
91.209.146.0/24
91.210.88.0/22
91.211.108.0/22
91.211.188.0/22
91.211.232.0/22
91.212.13.0/24
91.212.17.0/24
91.212.37.0/24
91.212.163.0/24
91.212.201.0/24
91.212.233.0/24
91.212.235.0/24
91.213.12.0/24
91.215.216.0/22
91.216.71.0/24
91.216.95.0/24
91.216.174.0/24
91.216.253.0/24
91.217.148.0/24
91.217.205.0/24
91.217.215.0/24
91.218.80.0/22
91.220.176.0/24
91.220.189.0/24
91.221.254.0/23
91.222.20.0/22
91.223.66.0/24
91.226.226.0/23
91.228.38.0/24
91.230.6.0/23
91.230.192.0/22
91.230.230.0/24
91.230.231.0/24
91.232.209.0/24
91.233.32.0/24
91.234.19.0/24
91.234.21.0/24
91.234.92.0/22
91.235.164.0/24
91.235.248.0/22
91.236.144.0/22
91.237.56.0/22
91.237.102.0/23
92.62.240.0/20
92.247.0.0/16
93.93.8.0/21
93.94.136.0/21
93.123.0.0/17
93.152.128.0/17
93.155.128.0/17
93.183.128.0/18
94.26.0.0/17
94.72.128.0/18
94.73.0.0/18
94.101.192.0/20
94.139.192.0/19
94.155.0.0/16
94.156.0.0/16
94.190.128.0/17
94.236.128.0/17
95.42.0.0/16
95.43.0.0/16
95.87.0.0/18
95.87.192.0/18
95.111.0.0/17
95.140.208.0/20
95.158.128.0/18
95.168.224.0/19
95.169.192.0/19
109.104.192.0/19
109.107.64.0/19
109.120.192.0/18
109.121.128.0/18
109.121.192.0/18
109.160.0.0/17
109.199.128.0/19
109.199.224.0/19
128.140.176.0/20
130.185.192.0/18
130.204.0.0/16
145.255.192.0/19
149.62.192.0/18
158.58.192.0/18
164.138.216.0/21
176.12.0.0/18
176.67.232.0/21
176.222.0.0/20
178.16.128.0/20
178.75.192.0/18
178.132.80.0/21
178.169.128.0/17
178.239.112.0/20
178.239.224.0/20
178.249.168.0/21
178.254.192.0/18
188.124.64.0/19
188.126.0.0/19
188.127.64.0/19
188.254.128.0/17
192.58.32.0/22
192.92.129.0/24
192.162.231.0/24
193.9.16.0/24
193.16.102.0/24
193.16.157.0/24
193.16.246.0/24
193.17.229.0/24
193.19.172.0/22
193.22.103.0/24
193.22.248.0/24
193.23.52.0/24
193.24.240.0/22
193.25.162.0/23
193.26.14.0/24
193.26.216.0/24
193.28.250.0/24
193.29.55.0/24
193.30.228.0/22
193.36.35.0/24
193.37.238.0/24
193.41.64.0/22
193.41.182.0/23
193.41.188.0/22
193.43.26.0/24
193.47.74.0/24
193.68.0.0/19
193.68.96.0/19
193.68.128.0/17
193.84.86.0/24
193.93.24.0/22
193.104.79.0/24
193.104.165.0/24
193.105.60.0/24
193.105.148.0/24
193.105.151.0/24
193.105.196.0/24
193.107.36.0/22
193.107.68.0/22
193.108.24.0/24
193.108.32.0/23
193.109.54.0/23
193.110.82.0/24
193.110.132.0/24
193.110.159.0/24
193.110.216.0/21
193.111.89.0/24
193.111.194.0/23
193.138.67.0/24
193.142.0.0/24
193.150.67.0/24
193.151.20.0/22
193.151.80.0/22
193.160.159.0/24
193.161.192.0/24
193.164.222.0/23
193.169.198.0/23
193.178.152.0/23
193.178.166.0/24
193.178.222.0/24
193.186.38.0/24
193.192.48.0/23
193.192.56.0/23
193.193.162.0/23
193.193.164.0/24
193.193.182.0/24
193.194.140.0/23
193.194.156.0/24
193.200.1.0/24
193.200.2.0/24
193.200.8.0/24
193.200.12.0/24
193.200.14.0/23
193.200.16.0/23
193.200.24.0/24
193.200.28.0/24
193.201.114.0/23
193.201.172.0/24
193.201.240.0/22
193.202.108.0/24
193.203.198.0/23
193.218.0.0/24
193.228.152.0/24
193.254.29.0/24
194.0.32.0/24
194.0.235.0/24
194.8.4.0/24
194.8.53.0/24
194.8.60.0/24
194.9.6.0/23
194.12.224.0/19
194.34.12.0/24
194.36.167.0/24
194.48.206.0/24
194.50.73.0/24
194.50.76.0/24
194.50.122.0/24
194.54.140.0/22
194.63.136.0/22
194.79.12.0/22
194.88.228.0/23
194.88.250.0/23
194.110.205.0/24
194.141.0.0/19
194.141.32.0/19
194.141.64.0/18
194.141.128.0/17
194.145.63.0/24
194.145.160.0/22
194.146.232.0/22
194.150.116.0/22
194.150.180.0/23
194.153.118.0/24
194.153.145.0/24
194.169.231.0/24
194.187.132.0/22
194.246.110.0/23
195.8.222.0/23
195.10.193.0/24
195.20.20.0/22
195.20.24.0/22
195.22.146.0/23
195.24.32.0/19
195.24.88.0/21
195.28.6.0/23
195.34.96.0/19
195.35.84.0/24
195.39.198.0/23
195.39.212.0/23
195.42.142.0/23
195.47.193.0/24
195.54.44.0/23
195.62.22.0/23
195.64.160.0/23
195.66.125.0/24
195.68.200.0/23
195.68.214.0/23
195.69.108.0/22
195.69.120.0/22
195.69.164.0/22
195.72.112.0/24
195.74.85.0/24
195.85.215.0/24
195.88.74.0/23
195.88.140.0/23
195.96.224.0/19
195.110.24.0/23
195.114.112.0/23
195.128.132.0/24
195.128.134.0/24
195.128.224.0/23
195.137.252.0/23
195.138.128.0/19
195.149.71.0/24
195.149.248.0/21
195.162.72.0/23
195.170.166.0/24
195.170.178.0/24
195.177.218.0/23
195.177.248.0/23
195.178.8.0/23
195.178.98.0/23
195.178.116.0/23
195.182.41.0/24
195.182.44.0/24
195.189.80.0/22
195.189.224.0/23
195.191.34.0/23
195.191.60.0/23
195.191.94.0/23
195.191.148.0/23
195.214.248.0/21
195.216.228.0/24
195.225.51.0/24
195.225.124.0/22
195.225.252.0/22
195.230.0.0/19
195.234.84.0/22
195.234.236.0/22
195.238.84.0/23
195.242.106.0/23
195.242.126.0/23
195.242.240.0/22
195.246.240.0/23
212.5.32.0/19
212.5.128.0/19
212.21.128.0/19
212.25.32.0/19
212.36.0.0/19
212.39.64.0/19
212.43.32.0/19
212.45.64.0/19
212.50.0.0/19
212.50.64.0/19
212.56.0.0/19
212.70.128.0/19
212.72.192.0/19
212.73.128.0/19
212.75.0.0/19
212.91.160.0/19
212.95.160.0/19
212.104.96.0/19
212.116.128.0/19
212.117.32.0/19
212.122.160.0/19
212.124.64.0/19
212.233.128.0/17
213.16.32.0/19
213.91.128.0/17
213.108.240.0/21
213.130.64.0/19
213.137.32.0/19
213.145.96.0/19
213.149.128.0/19
213.167.0.0/19
213.169.32.0/19
213.191.192.0/19
213.214.64.0/19
213.222.32.0/19
213.226.0.0/19
213.226.32.0/19
213.231.128.0/18
213.240.192.0/18
217.9.224.0/20
217.10.240.0/20
217.18.240.0/20
217.30.208.0/20
217.75.128.0/20
217.75.144.0/20
217.79.32.0/20
217.79.64.0/20
217.79.80.0/20
217.145.80.0/20
217.145.160.0/20
217.174.48.0/20
217.174.144.0/20
```

Comment: The thing is that I want to check i the user is from BG and then to set site language to bg and if there not to set it to en. So the .htaccess doesnt do the work.

Comment: What does .htaccess have to do with your question?  You asked how to check the IP against a country - you got the answers.  Now use this information to identify the country the user's coming from and do whatever you need based on this information.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to find out if an ip address is assigned to a given country without performing GeoIP on it.

Answer (score 0):

another way 
`$continent = geoip_continent_code_by_name('www.example.com');
if ($continent) {
    echo 'This host is located in: ' . $continent;
}`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-continent-code-by-name.php